# In VSE, how to change strip from movie to image (sequence) ?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, file-format, conversion

I have edited a movie, however I decided to start using image sequences.

I can easily change a movie to a different movie source, while preserving the edits.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a way to change it to image source.

Is there a way to do this? If not, how could I work around while keeping my edits?

Comment: it could be impossible, but you could use markers, at least, to track your "edits" (I guess mostly cuts?), so to rebuild them at the original positions...

Comment: you're right - cuts. I guess I'll have to stick to using movie clips with these. thank you